# Taking method of the related model into a separate column of jqgrid

Tags: django, orm, jqgrid

I am using django 1.4 together with `jqgrid` from `django_gems` package
The following code is trying to bring the `virtual` column onto the `grid` by concatenating first and last name.

However it fails with

> Cannot resolve keyword `client__get_fullname` into field.

Is there any acceptable way to achieve this?

```
 class Car(models.Model):
     number = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
 client = models.ForeignKey('Client')

 class Client(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
 last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
 def get_fullname(self):
     return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

 from django_gems.jqgrid
 import JqGrid
 class CarGrid(JqGrid):
     queryset = Car.objects.all()
 fields = ['number', 'client__get_fullname']

 jqgrid config = {
     "altRows": true,
     "rowList": [10, 25, 50, 100],
     "sortname": "id",
     "viewrecords": true,
     "autowidth": false,
     "forcefit": false,
     "shrinkToFit": false,
     "height": "auto",
     "colModel": [{
         "index": "id",
         "editable": false,
         "name": "id",
         "label": "ID"
     }, {
         "index": "number",
         "editable": false,
         "name": "number",
         "label": "number"
     }, {
         "index": "first_name",
         "editable": false,
         "name": "client__first_name",
         "label": "first name"
     }],
     "caption": "Cars",
     "datatype": "json",
     "gridview": true,
     "sortorder": "asc",
     "viewsortcols": true,
     "url": "main/examplegrid",
     "rowNum": 10,
     "pager": "#pager",
     "jsonReader": {
         "repeatitems": false
     }
 }

 sample data = {
     "total": 1,
     "records": 1,
     "rows": [{
         "client__first_name": "Bill",
         "client__last_name": "Clinton",
         "id": 1,
         "number": "111222"
     }],
     "page": 1
 }
```

Comment: You can fill the "virtual" column **on the client side** inside of [beforeProcessing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event. If you would append your question with jqGrid definition in JavaScript and with JSON data (at least one row) which will be posted to the client I would show you more detailed how you can do this.

Comment: Here you go. config with sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK! Let us you get the JSON data

```JSON
{
    "total": 1,
    "records": 1,
    "rows": [
        {
            "client__first_name": "Bill",
            "client__last_name": "Clinton",
            "id": 1,
            "number": "111222"
        }
    ],
    "page": 1
}
```

and the jqGrid contains an additional column

```
{name: "client__full_name", label: "full name"}
```

which should be constructed from `client__first_name` and `client__last_name`. In the case the most simplest way would be to use [beforeProcessing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events) callback function:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: "main/examplegrid",
    datatype: "json",
    colModel: [
        {name: "id", label: "ID"},
        {name: "client__first_name", label: "first name"},
        {name: "client__last_name", label: "last name"},
        {name: "client__full_name", label: "full name"}
    ],
    gridview: true,
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
    //... other parameters
    beforeProcessing: function (data) {
        var items = data.rows, n = items.length, i, item;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            item = items[i];
            item.client__full_name = item.client__first_name + ' ' +
                item.client__last_name;
        }
    }
});
```

The callback function `beforeProcessing` will be called by jqGrid after the data are received from the server and before the data will be processed. So in the simple way we can implement any "virtual" column.

Comment: This works fine. Thank you Oleg. How about making the toolbar searching  to work with this virtual column?

Comment: @user537723: You are welcome! All works exactly as in case of searching in the standard column. You should just extend your server code to analyse for "client__full_name" as the input field.